# How do I compile Cimgui (C++ library wrapper for C)?

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

I am trying to compile [Cimgui](https://github.com/cimgui/cimgui) library to use it with [GLEW](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew) and [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) in my C project. I am having trouble with the `cimgui_impl.h` file. I have quite a few of knowledge gaps when it comes to compiling with cmake, used only makefiles up to now.

From what I understood I have to compile only the library using the makefile or the cmake, then include the cimgui.h and generator/output/cimgui_impl.h in my C project. Afterwards link it against the library I compiled.

My include looks like this:

```
#define CIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS
#include "cimgui.h"
#include "cimgui_impl.h"
```

And my Makefile looks like this:

```
# CC:=clang
LD := g++ # not sure if I am using this right
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
BIN_DIR := bin

CFLAGS  := -g -march=native 
CFLAGS  += -pedantic -Wall 
CFLAGS += $(CDEFINES)
IFLAGS  := -Iinclude -Ilibs/cimgui/imgui -Ilibs/cimgui -Ilibs/cimgui/generator/output
LDFLAGS := -Llibs/build -lGL -lglfw -lm -lGLEW -lcollectc -lcglm libs/cimgui/build/cimgui.a

CFLAGS_REL := -DNDEBUG -O3 -march=native

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name "*.c")
OBJS := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

# add build/ to each object
TARGET_DBG:=$(BIN_DIR)/main

all: bin

$(OBJS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bin: $(TARGET_DBG)
$(TARGET_DBG): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) # using $(LD) here
```

I tried compiling the library statically both with the makefile `make static`. Also tried `cmake -S . -B build; cd build; make`, with CMakeLists.txt static option to "yes".

When I do this I get the following errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.o: in function `main':
/home/sam/dev/c/again-opengl/src/main.c:66:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sam/dev/c/again-opengl/src/main.c:67:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:33: bin/main] Error 1
```

Also tried to compile the backend_test/example_glfw_opengl3 using cmake and that works like a charm. I've spent few hours on this still am not sure what all do I need compile and include.

Comment: If you are using C++ libraries, you need to use the C++ compiler as a linker. Try adding `LD := g++`.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. But I added `LD := g++`, then I changed the `$(CC)` to `$(LD)`. Like this: `$(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)`, which only links the .o files. But I get these errors: ```/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.o: in function `main':
/home/sam/dev/c/again-opengl/src/main.c:66:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sam/dev/c/again-opengl/src/main.c:67:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init'```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Edited to the makefile in the cimgui lib directory
Added (lines 11, 12)

```
OBJS += ./imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.o
OBJS += ./imgui/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.o
```

and (line 51)

```
CXXFLAGS  += -DIMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS=1 -DIMGUI_IMPL_API="extern \"C\" " -DIMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_LOADER_GL3W -Dcimgui_EXPORTS
```

Copied flags from the backend_test/example_glfw_opengl3 compiled